# How can I edit an individual site's virtualhost using either WHM or cPanel?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, documentroot

I've been using Webmin/virtualmin for years. In Webmin, I can edit Apache config files quite easily. For example, if a user wants to change the DocumentRoot because he/she wants to serve up a Ruby on Rails app using Phusion Passenger, I can do that in a few seconds using the Webmin GUI.

/etc/apache/sites-available/samplesite.com.conf

Is there something similar in WHM/cPanel? How can I edit the VirtualHost (and inside that, the Document Root), using WHM/cPanel?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

generally this is done via shell - /usr/local/apache ... etc

You will however need to "distill" the change if you make it - otherwise a cPanel update and/or an EasyApache update will overwrite the change.

Shoot me an example of what your trying to do - and I can step you through it - provided the battery lasts a bit longer here while my children play @ ChuckECheese ...

---

You will need root level access to make any changes as well as distill the change - so it sticks w/ any new updates

---

It appears that you do not have root level access -  So this is not possible for you - furthermore - with the current state of Rails3 on cPanel - having root may not help anyhow.

Comment: I'm deploying a Rails 3 app, so I need to change the DocumentRoot. Here's what needs to be done. "Deploying a Ruby on Rails application: an example

Add a virtual host to your
Apache configuration file and set its DocumentRoot to /somewhere/public:

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.yourhost.com
DocumentRoot /somewhere/public # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
<Directory /somewhere/public>
AllowOverride all # <-- relax Apache security settings
Options -MultiViews # <-- MultiViews must be turned off
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>" I do this all frequently in Webmin, but I'm lost with WHM.

Comment: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/mongrel-issue-when-starting-ruby-applications-using-rails-3-0-case-43320-a-163993.html#post730411   

In Short - Since mongrel is being a mongrel ;-)   cPanel does not hav a date to support Rails3 as of yet. 

Their own staff have even suggested they support mod_rails with passenger over mongrel - might want to think about your approach first.

Comment: I've already installed Phusion Passenger and Rails 3. I won't be using cPanel to set up Rails. I just need to change the virtulhost. I tried sshing in as the user, but I wasn't able to get the virtualhost changed/setup.

Comment: I don't have root access on this server. I have to ssh in as the user.

Comment: Simply put - YOU CANNOT DO THIS.    Since cPanel would require you to have root abilities to make the change - you cannot do this w/ the host you are using.